# Do I need to provide in-text citations in a news article for school?

Tags: structure, citations, non-fiction, resources

So, for my Senior English Class, I need to write a news article about technology. However, I'm unsure as to whether or not I need in-text citations for said paper. Do I need in-text citations for a "news article", or do I need to do more research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

News articles generally put citations in the form of a quote.

"The firestorms are challenging, but we don't foresee shutting down electrical service to areas near the uncontained areas at this time," Javier Sanchez, operations manager for Golden State Electric & Gas, told reporters at a press conference this morning.

If you're reporting on things not as timely, and where a direct quote isn't important or even useful to have, you can still say things like "according to ___" or "in their latest white paper, ____ company says..."

Of course, the opinion that really counts is that of your teacher.  Ask her/him how to handle it.